# Simulate ROW_NUMBER in SQL 2000 combined with left outer joins

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

Iv'e read a few articles and read past SO posts but I cant seem to get my query working.

Basically I'm trying to add a RowNumber Column on a select query with Left Outer Joins.

It's strange that if I return the query with one field all works fine.

The original TSQL:

```
SELECT TOP 10 a.ACCOUNTID, 
              ACCOUNT, 
              a.LASTHISTORYBY, 
              a.LASTHISTORYDATE, 
              a.CreateDate, 
              a.[Type], 
              [Status], 
              Email, 
              Fax, 
              MainPhone, 
              WebAddress, 
              adr.ADDRESSID, 
              EntityID, 
              ADDRESS1, 
              ADDRESS2, 
              ADDRESS3, 
              ADDRESS4, 
              City, 
              adr.[State], 
              Postalcode, 
              County, 
              Country, 
              IsPrimary, 
              adr.CreateDate, 
              adr.CreateUser, 
              adr.ModifyDate, 
              adr.ModifyUser, 
              htaccount.SCHOOLCLOSED
FROM sysdba.ACCOUNT a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.[ADDRESS] adr ON a.ADDRESSID = adr.ADDRESSID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.[HT_ACCOUNT] htaccount ON a.ACCOUNTID = htaccount.ACCOUNTID
```

Obviusoly works great but trying to add a similar RowNumber feature is an absolute pain. When I run the new script the RowNumber seems to return into the 9k value. Also I see duplicate values.

The TSQL with RowNumber:

```
SELECT TOP 300 RowNumber, 
               a.ACCOUNTID, 
               a.LASTHISTORYBY, 
               a.LASTHISTORYDATE
  FROM (SELECT ACCOUNTID, 
               LASTHISTORYBY, 
               LASTHISTORYDATE, 
               (SELECT count(*) FROM sysdba.ACCOUNT AS t1 WHERE t1.ACCOUNTID <= t2.ACCOUNTID) AS RowNumber FROM sysdba.ACCOUNT AS t2) as a
  --LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.[ADDRESS] adr ON ADDRESSID = adr.ADDRESSID 
  --LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.[HT_ACCOUNT] htaccount ON a.ACCOUNTID = htaccount.ACCOUNTID
  WHERE RowNumber > 50 AND  RowNumber < 100
```

I commented out the Left Outer Joins because I was testing but ideally need the joins in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Comment: ah SQL SERVER 2000. such fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "row count" should contain all the relevant conditions as the main query (meaning meaning that it should be selected **after** the left join).
Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Base 
AS

SELECT        a.ACCOUNTID, 
              ACCOUNT, 
              a.LASTHISTORYBY, 
              a.LASTHISTORYDATE, 
              a.CreateDate, 
              a.[Type], 
              [Status], 
              Email, 
              Fax, 
              MainPhone, 
              WebAddress, 
              adr.ADDRESSID, 
              EntityID, 
              ADDRESS1, 
              ADDRESS2, 
              ADDRESS3, 
              ADDRESS4, 
              City, 
              adr.[State], 
              Postalcode, 
              County, 
              Country, 
              IsPrimary, 
              adr.CreateDate, 
              adr.CreateUser, 
              adr.ModifyDate, 
              adr.ModifyUser, 
              htaccount.SCHOOLCLOSED
FROM sysdba.ACCOUNT a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.[ADDRESS] adr ON a.ADDRESSID = adr.ADDRESSID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.[HT_ACCOUNT] htaccount ON a.ACCOUNTID = htaccount.ACCOUNTID
GO

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, (
               SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM vwBase t2
               WHERE t2.ACCOUNTID <= t1.ACCOUNTID) As RowNumber
    FROM vwBase t1
) iq
WHERE RowNumber > 50 AND RowNumber < 100
```

Also, you are missing an order by clause on both of your select statements. no point of selecting top x rows without order by.